# What to use instead of QStringList?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm new to Qt, so I'm not sure what to use.

I thought I would have a `QStringList` to give to my `QStringListModel` and display it in a `ListView`.

Now, however, I need to divide `QStringList` in the values of 2 types. So, I need to have string + some typeId, not just one string, but `QStringList` is for one-dimensional list only.

Anyone could give an advice on what is the best way to try to implement this?

Comment: You should add some code to the question, at least a piece of QML demonstrating how you intend to use this. But if you want "multidimensional" data, and there isn't too many rows in your model, consider using `QStandardItemModel` instead of `QStringListModel`.

Comment: Also study http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html even if it probably does not fit your use case (or maybe it does, hard to tell based just on what you write).

Comment: The answers is in the doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `QAbstractListModel` subclass as a *Qt Quick* model. An example of base class for a models (I use it for convenience):

```
// abstractobjectlistmodel.h
#pragma once

#include <QtCore>

struct AbstractObjectListModel
        : public QAbstractListModel
{

    explicit AbstractObjectListModel(QObject * const parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : QAbstractListModel{parent}
    { ; }

    int rowCount(QModelIndex const & parent = {}) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE Q_DECL_FINAL
    {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        return items.count();
    }

    QVariant data(QModelIndex const & index, const int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE Q_DECL_FINAL
    {
        if (!index.isValid()) {
            return {};
        }
        switch (role) {
        case Qt::UserRole : {
            return QVariant::fromValue(items[index.row()].data());
        }
        default : {
            return {};
        }
        }
    }

    QHash< int, QByteArray > roleNames() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE Q_DECL_FINAL
    {
        auto roleNames = QAbstractListModel::roleNames();
        roleNames.insert(Qt::UserRole, "modelData");
        return roleNames;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE
    virtual
    QObject * get(int row) const
    {
        if (row < 0) {
            return {};
        }
        if (row >= rowCount()) {
            return {};
        }
        return items[row];
    }

    void remove(int row, int count = 1)
    {
        Q_ASSERT(count > 0);
        Q_ASSERT(row >= 0);
        Q_ASSERT(row + count <= rowCount());
        beginRemoveRows({}, row, row + count - 1);
        while (0 < count) {
            items.takeAt(row)->deleteLater();
            --count;
        }
        endRemoveRows();
    }

    void clear()
    {
        if (!items.isEmpty()) {
            remove(0, rowCount());
        }
    }

protected :

    ~AbstractObjectListModel() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE Q_DECL_EQ_DEFAULT; // derived classes should not meant to be manipulated polymorphically

    QList< QPointer< QObject > > items;

    void insert(int row, QObject * const item)
    {
        item->setParent(this);
        beginInsertRows({}, row, row);
        items.insert(row, item);
        endInsertRows();
    }

    void append(QObject * const item)
    {
        insert(rowCount(), item);
    }

};
```

But one need to override `get` to access items' `Q_PROPERTY` properties (in addition to dynamic ones):

```
// type of element
class Project
        : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name MEMBER name NOTIFY nameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString path MEMBER path NOTIFY pathChanged)

public :

    Project(QString name, QString path,
            QObject * const parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : QObject{parent}
        , name{name}
        , path{path}
    { ; }

Q_SIGNALS :

    void nameChanged(QString name);
    void pathChanged(QString path);

private :

    QString name;
    QString path;

};

// custom model
class ProjectsListModel
        : public AbstractObjectListModel
{

    Q_OBJECT

public :

    explicit ProjectsListModel(QObject * const parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : AbstractObjectListModel{parent}
    { ; }

    void appendProject(QString name, QString path)
    {
        AbstractObjectListModel::append(::new Project{name, path});
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE
    Project *
    get(int row) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        return qobject_cast< Project * >(AbstractObjectListModel::get(row));
    }

};
```

Before use one need to register concrete model with `qmlRegisterType< ProjectsListModel >();`. Properties of `Project` class are avaliable in `delegate` and `highlight` by means of members of `modelData`.

Another example:

```
struct TimeZoneModel Q_DECL_FINAL
        : public QAbstractListModel
{

    Q_OBJECT

public :

    explicit TimeZoneModel(QObject * const parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : QAbstractListModel{parent}
    { ; }

    int rowCount(QModelIndex const & parent = {}) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        return timeZoneIds.count();
    }

    QVariant data(QModelIndex const & index, const int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        if (!index.isValid() || (role > Qt::UserRole + 4)) {
            return {};
        }
        QTimeZone timeZone{timeZoneIds[index.row()]};
        if (!timeZone.isValid()) {
            return {};
        }
        return roleData(timeZone, role);
    }

    QHash< int, QByteArray > roleNames() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        auto roleNames = QAbstractListModel::roleNames();
        int i = Qt::UserRole;
        for (const auto role : {"modelData", "id", "comment", "name", "country"}) {
            roleNames.insert(i++, role);
        }
        return roleNames;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE
    QByteArray get(int row) const
    {
        if (row < 0) {
            return {};
        }
        if (row >= rowCount()) {
            return {};
        }
        return timeZoneIds[row];
    }

private :

    QVariant roleData(QTimeZone const & timeZone, int role = Qt::UserRole) const
    {
        switch (role) {
        case Qt::UserRole : {
            QVariantMap modelData;
            const auto names = roleNames();
            while (++role < Qt::UserRole + 5) {
                modelData.insert(QString::fromUtf8(names[role]), roleData(timeZone, role));
            }
            return modelData;
        }
        case Qt::UserRole + 1: {
            return QString::fromUtf8(timeZone.id());
        }
        case Qt::UserRole + 2 : {
            return timeZone.comment();
        }
        case Qt::UserRole + 3 : {
            return timeZone.displayName(QTimeZone::StandardTime);
        }
        case Qt::UserRole + 4 : {
            return QLocale::countryToString(timeZone.country());
        }
        default : {
            return {};
        }
        }
    }

    const QByteArrayList timeZoneIds = QTimeZone::availableTimeZoneIds();

};
```

In addition to access via `modelData`'s fields (`modelData.id`, `modelData.comment` etc) all the symbols are accessible directly (i.e. `id`, `comment` etc) in `delegate` and `highlight` contexts of the `ListView`.

Model `TimeZoneModel` is `const` and can be injected into global scope directly without any performance drawbacks:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

TimeZoneModel timeZoneModel;
Q_SET_OBJECT_NAME(timeZoneModel);
qmlRegisterType< TimeZoneModel >();
const auto rootContext = engine.rootContext();
rootContext->setContextProperty(timeZoneModel.objectName(), &timeZoneModel);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need dictionary that contains QString and any other type I suggest you to use

```
  QMap<QString, YourType> myMap;
```

Here you have some example of usage:

```
QMap<int, QString> myMap;
myMap.insert(1,"A");
myMap.insert(2,"B");
myMap[3] = "C";

foreach(int i, myMap.keys()) qDebug() << myMap[i];
```

Comment: Why is this upvoted? OP is asking for a solution usable with a QML view. This answer isn't.